# Delete SMS from Hangout programmatically in android

Tags: android, smsmanager

Is there a problem with deleting the SMS programmatically in android KITKAT (4.4) - All messages are there in my app and Hangout even though it has been deleted using the below code?

```
 try 
            {
                String uri = "content://sms/" ;

                Log.e("Thread",""+threadId);
                getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), "thread_id ="+threadId, null);

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {

            }
```

The above code just works fine on all devices below KITKAT 4.4. Has anybody come across this problem? If so how to fix it?

Comment: Anybody who has tried deleting SMS programatically using Android KITKAT...

Comment: Yes, have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Sharing the code would be appreciated a lot..

Comment: @Krishna: Let me check on it will post it here. Give me two days.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, from Android KitKat your app need to be a default SMS app to make deleting message. You can read it but you can not delete it or mark it as read.